i-adjective + に
Stupid question I know, but I can't find any explanation as to what an i-adjective followed by に is supposed to mean. For example:

明日もアサッテも忙しいに決まってんだろ！

I know what everything else is, even the grammar, but the に is stumping me. I simple explanation of the grammatical structure is all I need.

に決まる is a special construction.
